# Trying to merge convert mult linestrings with breaks

Tags: postgis, merge, linestring

I am trying to clean up a road network file. The roads are encoded as multlinestrings I want them as linestrings.

Normally I would use st_mergeline to convert from a multilinestring to linestring. But my issues is that some of the multilinestring include 1 or more holes/breaks in the linestring. 
[image]

Where the two lines represent two  multilinestring I am just wondering if there is a sly way of inserting a bridge between the two strings.  This issue is come with  about 30% of my data.  I could resolve this issue by editing data with qgis.  But there must be a better way of sorting this problem out that hand editing all that data. Using functions like st_union result in a single geometry  object with it includes the break. I want to joint the two segments together.

Comment: this is not trivial; there are the `ST_Snap` or `ST_SnapToGrid` functions that you could try to carefully apply on the vertices of the linestrings. *pgRouting* has efficiently implemented that in it's `pgr_nodeNetwork` function that might be a good option, also if you plan to do routing. PostGIS topology functions could also be applied here, but that requires some work on the data I guess.

Comment: Thanks, I resolve my problem by fixing the data source.

I did try some of the postgres topolgical tools as well with mixed results

There is a blog about using Postgis topologies to clean up road networks at http://blog.mathieu-leplatre.info/use-postgis-topologies-to-clean-up-road-networks.html